# Disable language prefix for non-default languages

Tags: i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I'm migrating a plain multilanguage HTML site to Drupal 7. One of the requirements of the migration is to preserve the current URLs of each page. Right now, the site has three languages and has URLs like these:
www.example.com/files/content1/es.html
www.example.com/files/content1/en.html

I've Internationalization and Pathauto modules enabled, and set the pattern for the node alias like this:
files/[node:title]/[node:language].html

However, the i18n module adds a prefix to the URL, like this:
www.example.com/es/files/content1/es.html
www.example.com/en/files/content1/en.html

In Language options, in Detection, I've enabled URL.
I've been able to remove the prefix for the default language, but I'm unable to remove it for the other languages. So, in the end, I have URLs like these:
www.example.com/files/content1/es.html
www.example.com/en/files/content1/en.html

How can I remove the prefix for the other languages too?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think that you can't because different url for different languages is needed...

Comment: But different languages will have different URLs. Spanish pages will end with es.html, and english pages will end with en.html.

Answer (score 0):

Path redirection from old paths to new may be a solution (workarround really). This is compatible with SEO https://drupal.org/project/redirect